# Remove ViewModel name from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a URL that looks like this

```
https://localhost/app/result?HomeViewModel.Prop1=Indiana+PA&HomeViewModel.Prop2=1
```

`HomeViewModel` is a Property of another ViewModel

Is there a way I can remove `HomeViewModel` from the URL, so it look likes this

```
https://localhost/app/result?Prop1=Indiana+PA&Prop2=1
```

Form that submits the parameters

```
@model CSharp.Models.ViewModels.ResultViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Result", new { ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Get, new { role = "form" }))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HomeViewModel.Prop1)
   @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.HomeViewModel.Prop2)
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(ResultViewModel model)
{
   var value1 = model.HomeViewModel.Prop1;
   var value2 = model.HomeViewModel.Prop2;

    var rvm = new ResultViewModel
    {
       otherProps = linq(value1),
       otherProps = linq(value2),
    };
  return View(rvm);
}
```

Comment: How are you generating the url?

Comment: It be heplful if you would provide your controller action code.

Comment: Not using the code you have shown - your generating a `<select>` element with `name="HomeViewModel.Prop1"` (although I assume thats a typo and its really `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.HomeViewModel.Prop2)`, not `Prop1`) so that is what will be posted. Use a view model with a property named `Prop2`

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Just change `ResultViewModel` to contain properties `Prop1` and `Prop2` so that in the view its `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop1)` etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please write an answer for your last comment? Rather than include the model that has both `Prop1` and `Prop2` as a property of a ViewModel, your suggestion works for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your view is generating inputs that have `name="HomeViewModel.Prop1"` and `name="HomeViewModel.Prop2"` and a form posts back the name/value pairs of its form controls. If you want the the query string to be generated with `.../result?Prop1=Indiana+PA&Prop2=1`, then modify your view model to contain properties with those names

```
public class ResultViewModel
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public yourEnumType Prop2 { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop1)
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Prop2)
```

and modify the POST method to

```
public ActionResult Index(ResultViewModel model)
{
   var value1 = model.Prop1;
   var value2 = model.Prop2;
   ....
```

Comment: Sir can you please help me with this question please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348733/merge-2-list-and-arrange-merged-list-based-on-rank

Answer (score 1):

First declare local variables

```
@{
    var Prop1 = Model.HomeViewModel.Prop1;
    var Prop2 = Model.HomeViewModel.Prop2;
}
```

then reference local variables instead of `Model`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Prop1)
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => Prop2)
```

Comment: I'm getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on `var Prop1 = Model.HomeViewModel.Prop1;` and most likely the second `var Prop1 = Model.HomeViewModel.Prop2;`