# Merge two lists and arrange merged list based on rank

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists and I am trying to merge them and after merging, my list should be in ascending order by rank.

**Code :**

```
 public class Test
    {
        public int TestId { get; set; }
        public List<VariantsRank> VariantsRanks { get; set; }
    }

    public class VariantsRank
    {
        public int VariantId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
    }
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Process()
        {
            var List1 = new Test();
            List1.TestId = 100;
            List1.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 10, Name = "V1", Rank = 0 });
            List1.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 11, Name = "V2", Rank = 1 });
            List1.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 12, Name = "V3", Rank = 2 });
            List1.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 13, Name = "V4", Rank = 3 });
            List1.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 14, Name = "V5", Rank = 4 });

            List1.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 15, Name = "V6", Rank = 5 });
            List1.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 16, Name = "V7", Rank = 6 });
            List1.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 17, Name = "V8", Rank = 7 });

            var List2 = new Test();
            List2.TestId = 100;
            List2.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 17, Name = "V8", Rank = 0 });
            List2.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 15, Name = "V6", Rank = 1 });
            List2.VariantsRanks.Add(new VariantsRank { VariantId = 16, Name = "V7", Rank = 2 });
            List2.VariantsRanks.Concat(List1.VariantsRanks).GroupBy(x => x.VariantId).SelectMany(x => x.Take(1)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

**Output I am getting** :

```
VariantId = 10, Name = "V1", Rank = 0
VariantId = 11, Name = "V2", Rank = 1
VariantId = 12, Name = "V3", Rank = 2
VariantId = 13, Name = "V4", Rank = 3
VariantId = 14, Name = "V5", Rank = 4

VariantId = 15, Name = "V6", Rank = 5
VariantId = 16, Name = "V7", Rank = 6
VariantId = 17, Name = "V8", Rank = 7
```

**Expected output :**

```
List1.TestId = 100
[0] : VariantId = 10, Name = "V1", Rank = 0
[1] : VariantId = 11, Name = "V2", Rank = 1
[2] : VariantId = 12, Name = "V3", Rank = 2
[3] : VariantId = 13, Name = "V4", Rank = 3
[4] : VariantId = 14, Name = "V5", Rank = 4
[5] : VariantId = 17, Name = "V8", Rank = 5
[6] : VariantId = 15, Name = "V6", Rank = 6
[7] : VariantId = 16, Name = "V7", Rank = 7
```

Now I would like to merge 2 list and for those records which are matching in list1 then I would like to give priority to list 2 records so v8,v6 and v7 of list 2 should replace list 1 records i.e v6,v7 and v8.

Comment: You say: _expected out if you will see then V8 is at 5th position because its rank is 5th in my list2_ But does not V8 have rank 0 in list 2? Also does all VariantId in list 2 always exist in list 1?

Comment: @Magnus :Sorry for the mistake. I  have updated my question

Comment: And if there is no matching item in list2 should it be included in the end result? For example if there was an item `v505` in list2?

Comment: @Magnus :Yes that is right at the end of the result

Comment: Are the lists ordered to begin with?

Comment: @Magnus.:List1 records will be order by rank in ascending order and new List i.e List2 records will also be ordered by rank in ascending order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136175/discussion-between-learning-and-magnus).

Comment: Please define how the first element in your second list, 17, which has as rank 0, in the resulted list this will take 5th position in your ranking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understand it, the problem can be defined this way. Given a two ordered lists, reorder the matching items in the first list according to their order in the second list, add unmatched items from the second list at the end of the first list.

I would start by preparing a queue of the ordered matches from the second list:

```
var matchQueue = new Queue<VariantsRank>(
    from r2 in List2.VariantsRanks
    join r1 in List1.VariantsRanks on r2.VariantId equals r1.VariantId
    orderby r2.Rank
    select r2);
```

then a `HashSet` with matched keys:

```
var matchSet = new HashSet<int>(matchQueue.Select(r2 => r2.VariantId));
```

We are going to process the first list in order, then for each element will use the `matchSet` to determine if there is match, and if yes, will take the **next match in order** using the prepared `matchQueue`.

Then we'll append the unmatched elements from the second list in order. Finally we'll iterate the resulting sequence (which should be ordered correctly from the previous steps) and update the ranks.

All that translated to LINQ looks like this:

```
var result = List1.VariantsRanks
    .OrderBy(r1 => r1.Rank)
    .Select(r1 => matchSet.Contains(r1.VariantId) ? matchQueue.Dequeue() : r1)
    .Concat(List2.VariantsRanks
    .Where(r2 => !matchSet.Contains(r2.VariantId))
    .OrderBy(r2 => r2.Rank))
    .Select((r, i) => new VariantsRank { VariantId = r.VariantId, Name = r.Name, Rank = i })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the first solution that came to my mind:

```
var result=List1.VariantsRanks.Union(List2.VariantsRanks)
                .GroupBy(e=>e.VariantId)
                .Select(g=>g.OrderBy(e=>e.Rank).FirstOrDefault())
                .OrderBy(e=>e.RankId);
```

**Explanation:**

1. Join both list
2. group variant by `VariantId`
3. Order each group by `Rank` and keep only the first one
4. Order the resulted list by `Rank`

Comment: exactly, is to order the first element that I get from each group

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Sorry but by mistake i have put wrong order no in my 2nd list.See my updated question for List2 and sorry once again.

Comment: that changes a little the things.Let me see what I can do

Comment: For those records which are common in list1 and list2 then i would like to replace list 1 records with list2 records(only common records)

Comment: The number of elements to rank is fixed, 8?

Comment: No it is not fixed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136174/discussion-between-learning-and-octavioccl).